# how to use middleware of the auth before route to get token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, middleware

How can I solve this?
i want get token in router and then router send response.but in this middle ware my code get token after routes called.and how can i access middleware token for verify user

```js
var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var router = express.Router();
var supertoken;
tokenmiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("this is auth middleware");
  try {
    var options = {
        method: "POST",
        url: "here is my auth server url",
        headers: {
          json: true,
          Authorization: "", //
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      },
      form: {
        grant_type: "password",
        username: "usrename",
        password: "password"
      };
    request(options, function(error, response, body1) {
      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      } else {
        let info = JSON.parse(body1);
        //it parse the body1 into json so we can use property of body1.
        supertoken = info.access_token; //it gives the token of the super admin.
        // console.log(supertoken)
        // console.log(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        //return supertoken
      }
    });
    console.log("superrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
    console.log(supertoken);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth Failed." });
  }
}; //this middleware gave me a token.



router.post("/verifyUser", tokenmiddleware, (req, res) => {
  //here i want my middleware token (but it calls after the route)
  //here i applied logic of verify user but token is not working.(it say's undefined)
});
```

Comment: Please format your code to be readable.  You have very few spaces, missing and wrong indentation.  You will be more likely to get people to help you here if you put some effort into making your question easy to read and understand. We are all volunteers.  We pay more attention to questions that are easy to understand. I honestly could not read your code without copying it out to an editor and running it through some code formatter to provide a consistent, readable style so I gave up trying to understand it.

Comment: FYI, `if (error) {throw new Error(error)` inside an asynchronous callback should NEVER, ever exist.  This does nothing useful.  It just throws back into some asynchronous code stub where you can never catch it.  You need real error handling and you should never even write code with that in it to start with.

Comment: my question is i can not get supertoken value (which is in middleware in request method).i want this value for authenticaton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware includes request which is an asynchronous operation. And you call `next()` outside of request callback. After your middleware called you fire `next()` before request is finished, just move next inside request callback

```
    tokenmiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
      console.log('this is auth middleware');
      try {
        var options = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'here is my auth server url',
          headers: {
            json: true,
            Authorization: '', //
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          form: {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: 'usrename',
            password: 'password',
          },
        };
        request(options, function(error, response, body1) {
          if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
          } else {
            let info = JSON.parse(body1);
            //it parse the body1 into json so we can use property of body1.
            supertoken = info.access_token; //it gives the token of the super admin.
            // console.log(supertoken)
            console.log('superrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr');
            console.log(supertoken);
            req.userToken = info.access_token;
            next();
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Auth Failed.' });
      }
    };

router.post("/verifyUser", tokenmiddleware, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.userToken); // should be your token
});
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to use supertoken of middleware inside router.post() because i want to pass in header which is inside of another request function of route.post()

Comment: Not sure I understood you correct but you can add token value as additional parameter to your request object. I've updated and answer